# Why does Safari 12.1 (and older) crash with this font applied to <select>?

Tags: css, fonts, safari, html-select

I'm using a font in `woff2` format on the `<select>` elements:

```css
select {
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
}
```

It causes Safari 12.1 and older to crash when I open the dropdown. I've heard this is a recognized issue in these older Safari browsers, but I'm still not sure how should I import the font to fix the crash.

Here's how I do it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">
```

And then in `font.css`:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Outfit";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(./Outfit.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
    U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

What is it that the older Safaris don't like about my CSS?

Comment: I assume you've already checked [browser compatibility?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Maybe check your relative urls? Per MDN: _Relative URLs, if used, are relative to the URL of the stylesheet (not to the URL of the web page)._

Comment: @fnostro it works everywhere except Safari 12.1 and lower.

Comment: @fnostro also, I think that the font is loaded properly, it works. It's just that it causes the open `<select>` to crash the browser.

Comment: OK. not much more I can offer. I did a quick search and found something about Safari 13.x crashing when select has a piece of CSS: `text-rendering: optimizelegibility;`